# get the word inside a special character and append to an array

Tags: php

so I have this email template that consist of something of a template strings

```
<p>My name is {name}</p>
```

that later on, when I trigger email function, I can just do `file_get_contents` and use str_replace to replace that part with the correct value

```
$temp = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/template/advertise.html');
$temp = str_replace('{img}','mysite.com/assets/img/face.jpg',$temp);
```

Now what wanted this time is to get those word inside `{}` and append to an array `$words = [];`

What I've tried is using explode technique e.g.

```
$word = 'Hello {img}, age {age}, I live in {address}';

$word = explode('}',$word);

$words = [];

foreach( $word as $w ){
  $words[] = explode('{',$w)[1];
}

print_r($words);
```

but is there other better way to do this? any ideas, help?

Comment: Try using preg_match_all which should match all words fitting the pattern like `/\{([^\}]+)\}/`

Comment: Hi, I believe you can use `preg_match` to find multiple groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$word = 'Hello {img}, age {age}, I live in {address}';

if (preg_match_all('/\{([^\}]+)\}/', $word, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);  
}
```

It should return all the variable names inside the curly braces.